# Error adding playlist in yt-dlp discord.py

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, yt-dlp

My bot is on Heroku.

```
[youtube:tab] PL4fGSI1pDJn5kI81J1fYWK5eZRl1zJ5kM: Downloading webpage
WARNING: [youtube:tab] unable to extract yt initial data; please report this issue on  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp , filling out the "Broken site" issue template properly. Confirm you are on the latest version using  yt-dlp -U
WARNING: [youtube:tab] Incomplete yt initial data received. Retrying ...
[youtube:tab] PL4fGSI1pDJn5kI81J1fYWK5eZRl1zJ5kM: Downloading webpage (retry #1)
WARNING: [youtube:tab] unable to extract yt initial data; please report this issue on  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp , filling out the "Broken site" issue template properly. Confirm you are on the latest version using  yt-dlp -U
WARNING: [youtube:tab] Incomplete yt initial data received. Retrying ...
[youtube:tab] PL4fGSI1pDJn5kI81J1fYWK5eZRl1zJ5kM: Downloading webpage (retry #2)
WARNING: [youtube:tab] unable to extract yt initial data; please report this issue on  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp , filling out the "Broken site" issue template properly. Confirm you are on the latest version using  yt-dlp -U
WARNING: [youtube:tab] Incomplete yt initial data received. Retrying ...
[youtube:tab] PL4fGSI1pDJn5kI81J1fYWK5eZRl1zJ5kM: Downloading webpage (retry #3)
WARNING: [youtube:tab] unable to extract yt initial data; please report this issue on  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp , filling out the "Broken site" issue template properly. Confirm you are on the latest version using  yt-dlp -U
WARNING: [youtube:tab] Incomplete yt initial data received
ERROR: [youtube:tab] PL4fGSI1pDJn5kI81J1fYWK5eZRl1zJ5kM: Playlists that require authentication may not extract correctly without a successful webpage download. If you are not downloading private content, or your cookies are only for the first account and channel, pass "--extractor-args youtubetab:skip=authcheck" to skip this check
```

If I write to the heroku console:

> yt-dlp --cookies cookies.txt https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSdfU8nTff5QcNqq-muG9AZrYiVy4S3zV

the download of music starts (music is not played), but each time it is not very good to write a command to the console.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed from code: `"cookiefile": "/config/cookies/cookies.txt"`
and everything worked